# Associated in 3 table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-7

I have to create 3rd table having assosisted with 2nd.

```
1st table: Schema
2nd table: Entity 
3rd table: Fields
```

Relation between them is:

```
Schema(id) ===>  Entity
Entity(id) ===> Fields
```

I have created table and views till Entity but don't know how to create table for field

Fields having values as:

```
"clientId"
"name"
"description"
"mnemonic"
"columnType"
"display"
"fallbackId"
"conceptDisplay"
"businessName"
```

Help me to create model and views for it to show all the fiels related to entity:

I tried something like this:

entity.rb => model

```
class Entity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :schema
  has_many :fields, dependent: :destroy
end
```

field.rb => model

```
class Field < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :entity
end
```

schema.rb => model

```
class Schema < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :entities, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :fields, through: :entities

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :schemaId, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

controller for field:

```
class FieldsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @field = Schema.find_by(id: params[:id]).fields
  end
end
```

views for entity where i have to create link_to to show all field for that entity

```
<div class="content">
  <ul>
  <% @entities.each do |data| %>
    <li>
      <%= data.clientId %>
      <%= link_to data.name, fields_index_path(id: data.id) %>
      <%= data.description %>
      <%= data.mnemonic %>
    </li>

  <% end %>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create these migrations:

```rb
  def change
    create_table :schemas do |t|
      # here all your necessary fields for schema
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

```rb
  def change
    create_table :entities do |t|
      t.references :schema, null: false, foreign_key: true
      # here all your necessary fields for entity
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

```rb
def change
  create_table :fields do |t|
    t.references :entity, null: false, foreign_key: true
    # here all your necessary fields for field
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

And add all necessary associations to your models

```rb
# schema.rb
class Schema < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :entities
  has_many :fields, through: :entities
end
```

```rb
# entiry.rb
class Entity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :schema
  has_many :fields
end
```

```rb
# field.rb
class Field < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :entiry
end
```

Fetch all `fields` for `Schema` through `Entity` in yout controller

```rb
# fields_controller.rb
class FieldsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @fields = Schema.find_by(id: params[:id]).fields
  end
end
```

And render all links to your fields in view

```rb
# views/fields/index.html.erb
<% @fields.each do |field| %>
  <%= link_to field.name, field_path(field) %>
<% end %>
```

And add necessary resources to your `routes`

```rb
# configs/routes
resources :schemas
resources :fields
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the help but you wrote: 
Fetch all fields for Schema in yout controller
but fields are assosiated with entity because each entity have many fields

Comment: Yes, your fields table belongs to entity and entity belongs to schema, and you can fetch all your fields through entities
Schema -> Entities -> Fields
If you need only entities for schema you can write Schema.find_by(id: params[:id]).entities.

Comment: Plz take a look at through  associations in Rails https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Hey Can you help me with this please:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73098279/rails-bootstrap-modal-is-not-showing